# Merge Object preserving it's value using addition in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization, duplicates, array-merge

I have the js object array structured as given below,

```js
items= [
    {
      discount: 27.6,
      name: 'Floy Vandervort',
      price: 230,
      quantity: 3,
      taxable: 662.4
    },
    {
      discount: 122.88,
      name: 'Adriel Abshire II',
      price: 256,
      quantity: 6,
      taxable: 1413.12
    },
    {
      discount: 159.66,
      name: 'Tabitha Stroman',
      price: 887,
      quantity: 2,
      taxable: 1614.34
    },
    {
      discount: 27.6,
      name: 'Floy Vandervort',
      price: 230,
      quantity: 3,
      taxable: 662.4
    },
    {
      discount: 122.88,
      name: 'Adriel Abshire II',
      price: 256,
      quantity: 6,
      taxable: 1413.12
    },
    {
      discount: 159.66,
      name: 'Tabitha Stroman',
      price: 887,
      quantity: 2,
      taxable: 1614.34
    },
    {
      discount: 27.6,
      name: 'Floy Vandervort',
      price: 230,
      quantity: 3,
      taxable: 662.4
    },
    {
      discount: 122.88,
      name: 'Adriel Abshire II',
      price: 256,
      quantity: 6,
      taxable: 1413.12
    },
    {
      discount: 159.66,
      name: 'Tabitha Stroman',
      price: 887,
      quantity: 2,
      taxable: 1614.34
    }
  ]
```

I want to avoid duplication of objects based on `name` property. So I decided to merge them by preserving its evaluation as illustrated below,

**Use Case**

consider property `name`, here in above array *Floy Vandervort* repeats 3 times. To convert it into a single object, merge them into a single object by preserving the value by addition. So, the properties `discount`, `quantity` and `taxable` should be merged by addition except for `price` property.

I'm looking for an optimal solution, I achieved using iterating over the original array and pushing merged object to another array. I want to eliminate the complexity, is it possible? if yes, how? Here is the function I'm using

```js
function(items) {
  let filtered = [];
  items.forEach((item) => {
    if (!isContains(filtered, item)) {
      filtered.push(item);
    } else {
      index = filtered.findIndex((x) => x.name === item.name);
      filtered[index].discount += item.discount;
      filtered[index].quantity += item.quantity;
      filtered[index].taxable += item.taxable;
    }
  });

  return filtered;
}

function isContains(items, ob) {
  items.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.name === ob.name) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance I just made an edit and placed the code I'm using.

Comment: @CertainPerformance that's what I want, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning inside a `forEach` callback has no effect - `isContains` will always return false. Better to use an object or Map indexed by the name instead, to reduce computational complexity by an order of magnitude - then you can get that object's values to get the array you want:

```js
const items=[{discount:27.6,name:"Floy Vandervort",price:230,quantity:3,taxable:662.4},{discount:122.88,name:"Adriel Abshire II",price:256,quantity:6,taxable:1413.12},{discount:159.66,name:"Tabitha Stroman",price:887,quantity:2,taxable:1614.34},{discount:27.6,name:"Floy Vandervort",price:230,quantity:3,taxable:662.4},{discount:122.88,name:"Adriel Abshire II",price:256,quantity:6,taxable:1413.12},{discount:159.66,name:"Tabitha Stroman",price:887,quantity:2,taxable:1614.34},{discount:27.6,name:"Floy Vandervort",price:230,quantity:3,taxable:662.4},{discount:122.88,name:"Adriel Abshire II",price:256,quantity:6,taxable:1413.12},{discount:159.66,name:"Tabitha Stroman",price:887,quantity:2,taxable:1614.34}];

function squish(items) {
  const squishedItemsByName = items.reduce((a, { name, ...props }) => {
    if (!a[name]) {
      a[name] = { name };
    }
    Object.entries(props).forEach(([prop, val]) => {
      a[name][prop] = (a[name][prop] || 0) + val;
    });
    return a;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(squishedItemsByName);
}

console.log(squish(items));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let h = {};
items.forEach(x=> h[x.name]= !h[x.name] ? x : {
      discount: h[x.name].discount+x.discount,
      name: x.name,
      price: x.price,
      quantity: h[x.name].quantity+x.quantity,
      taxable: h[x.name].taxable+x.taxable
    });

let result = Object.keys(h).map(k=> h[k]);
```

```js
items= [
    {
      discount: 27.6,
      name: 'Floy Vandervort',
      price: 230,
      quantity: 3,
      taxable: 662.4
    },
    {
      discount: 122.88,
      name: 'Adriel Abshire II',
      price: 256,
      quantity: 6,
      taxable: 1413.12
    },
    {
      discount: 159.66,
      name: 'Tabitha Stroman',
      price: 887,
      quantity: 2,
      taxable: 1614.34
    },
    {
      discount: 27.6,
      name: 'Floy Vandervort',
      price: 230,
      quantity: 3,
      taxable: 662.4
    },
    {
      discount: 122.88,
      name: 'Adriel Abshire II',
      price: 256,
      quantity: 6,
      taxable: 1413.12
    },
    {
      discount: 159.66,
      name: 'Tabitha Stroman',
      price: 887,
      quantity: 2,
      taxable: 1614.34
    },
    {
      discount: 27.6,
      name: 'Floy Vandervort',
      price: 230,
      quantity: 3,
      taxable: 662.4
    },
    {
      discount: 122.88,
      name: 'Adriel Abshire II',
      price: 256,
      quantity: 6,
      taxable: 1413.12
    },
    {
      discount: 159.66,
      name: 'Tabitha Stroman',
      price: 887,
      quantity: 2,
      taxable: 1614.34
    }
  ]

let h = {};
items.forEach(x=> h[x.name]= !h[x.name] ? x : {
      discount: h[x.name].discount+x.discount,
      name: x.name,
      price: x.price,
      quantity: h[x.name].quantity+x.quantity,
      taxable: h[x.name].taxable+x.taxable
    });
    
let result = Object.keys(h).map(k=> h[k]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of many ways of doing this could be the following :

```
const uniqueItems = Object.values(
    items.reduce((hashMap, item) => { 
        if (!hashMap[item.name]) {
            hashMap[item.name] = { ...item };
        } else {
            // You should use a safest way to add 
            hashMap[item.name].discount += item.discount;
            hashMap[item.name].price += item.price;
            hashMap[item.name].quantity += item.quantity;
            hashMap[item.name].taxable += item.taxable;
        }

        return hashMap;
    }, {})
)
```